# Python tkinter keeping window on top when focusing on another window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a text editor, and I have made a find/replace function with it's own window. 
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlVBY.jpg). I want it to become transparent when changing back to the main text window, but stay there. (Like what notepad++ does).
As you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/8KfCH), the find window is in front of the main window but it is transparent.

I already know I can use this to make the window transparent:

```
find_window.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
```

But now I want it to stay on top while the focus is on the other window.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself. I had to use the focus_out event and then use .lift() to place it on top:

```
def leave():
    find_window.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
    find_window.lift()

find_window.bind('<FocusOut>', leave)
```